# Assess quality of a Poisson regression model on R

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

we did a Poisson regression because we figured out that our data are count data.

Could you kindly explain us where we have to look at in order to understand the quality of our Poisson regression?

Thank you very much for your  help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Rootogram**

A *rootogram* could be a helpful visual in detecting whether there are problems with your model fit. The *countreg* package has a rootogram() function.

See Dr. Gavin Simpson's excellent blog post on rootograms: https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/06/07/rootograms/.

See also the article **Visualizing Count Data Regressions Using Rootograms** by Kleiber and Zeileis: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.01311.pdf.

**Simulated Residual Plots**

You can also look at the (simulated) residual plots that would be produced by the **DHARMa** package, as explained in the **Owl example (count data)** in this DHARMa vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html#lm-and-glm.

**Default Residual Plots**

Finally, you can apply the plot() function to your fitted model object and examine the default diagnostics produced by R for the fitted model, though these plots are known to be more difficult to interpret compared to the plots produced from simulated residuals.